# How to do "if feild1 = 1 than feild 2 != 2" in elastics search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have query like:

```
 "must_not": [{
               "term": { "institutionShare": "0"}
              },
              {
               "terms": {"typeId": ["4", "5"]}
              }
            ],
```

type id can be `[3,4,5]`

I wont to replace my query , so instead of `typeId in [4,5]` i wont to do `typeId not 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can realise that by combining your query with a boolean query. By using a must_not combined by term you realise a typeId not 3 for example:

```
  "must_not": [{
    "term": {"typeId": "3"}
        }
    ]
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand.  only if institutionShare is 0, than typeId can not be 3

Comment: you will have to add this case in an seperate must query, if u want to find those documents only. Have a look at the bool query docu [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: I not find way to do what i wont. if institutionShare = 1, than allow all typeIs, if is 0, than allow only type 3.